# How to keep spacing of text in div constant even with min-height (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a post a status kind of thing in javascript and in the "compose a post" div, there is centered text that says "enter your text here" (with contenteditable) and when you enter a new line in that text, the div expands. However, it does not keep the space between the text and the bottom of the div.
How could I preserve the space between the text and bottom of div, while expanding the page?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding padding-bottom to #body?

Comment: #body{padding-bottom:5px}

Comment: Didn't quite work -- same problem still there. @Michelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding to the `#body`:

```
#body {
    ...
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Remove the following properties from `#thirdspan`:

```
position: relative;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
```

And add the `box-sizing` to `#body`:

```
#body {
    ...
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Change #body to body. But you don't really need that for this solution.

Comment: oops sorry. I didn't see he is using #body for that part.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding to get spacing around instead of using position relative and make the third span block element.

```
#thirdspan{
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uX7HG/6/).